# Module not found: Can't resolve './edit-alarm/Days'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After trying to import a file, I got this message multiple times:

> Module not found: Can't resolve './edit-alarm/Days' in '/Users/home/Documents/my-app/src/add-new-alarm'

[Screenshot of my hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faI4u.png)

I don't really know what I am doing wrong or how to solve the problem.

NewDays.js (in add-new-alarm folder)

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { Days } from './edit-alarm/Days';

function NewDays() {
    return(
        Days.callDays() 
    )
}

export default NewDays;
```

Days.js (in edit-alarm folder)

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class Days extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            checked: false, 
            btnLists: []
        }
    }

updateClick = () => {
    [some code]
}

DayButtons = () => {
    return(
        [some code]
    )
}

callDays = () => {
    return (
        [some code]
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        this.callDays()
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your resolve path goes wrong. Try

```
import Days from '../edit-alarm/Days';
```

Comment: I just tried it out and it said: Attempted import error: 'Days' is not exported from '../edit-alarm/Days', is there something else that I can do?

Comment: You've exported a default class, so you just import it without `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
import Days from '../edit-alarm/Days';
```

without the curly braces